# AWS SAM and DynamoDB table in production

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM to define my app, and I am defining a DynamoDB table using this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-tablename

However, I am worried that in Prod, this will lead to deleting the table and its content.

How do others handle this? Is there a way to keep the table and not drop and recreate it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [changesets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html) and check them carefully to ensure that you are not causing a replacement of the table.
2. Use [`Deletion` and `UpdateReplace`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-product-attribute-reference.html) policies to ensure you do not lose data, even if you do replace it by accident.
3. Use a [stack policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html) to block updates to the resource